# SQL Server : AFTER UPDATE enter before column name

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables:

**Employee**

```
Id Name
----------
1  John
2  Mick
3  smith
```

When I modify smith record it fetch mick name in db when I did mick name its inserted john name

```
ALTER TRIGGER Dummyupdates
ON dummy1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @timeofdate DATETIME
    DECLARE @typeofaction VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @dummyName VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @dummyName = DummyName 
    FROM Employee

    SET @typeofaction = 'updated'

    INSERT INTO Audt_dumy (timeofdate, dummyName, typeofaction)   
    VALUES (GETDATE(), @dummyName, @typeofaction)
END
```

Comment: Any SQL Server trigger that fails to use `inserted` or `deleted` is probably broken (as yours is). Even once you start using them, any trigger that assumes that they contain exactly one row (instead of 0, 1 or multiple rows) is also broken. Triggers should be *set* based, not working with scalar variables.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Should include that comment as the header for the triggers tag tbph.

Comment: @JacobH - unfortunately, a) the triggers tag isn't specific to SQL and b) even if it was, other database products do offer per-row triggers.  It would be nice if there was a "you've applied this combination of tags, have you considered this?" set of content, but who should decide how that works. (Here, the combination of sql-server and triggers should trigger that content)